# System.Web.Http.Description is missing from Add Reference List

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am getting an error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?) c:\users\klippiat\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TfsPortal\TfsPortal\Models\ApiModel.cs  5   23  TfsPortal
```

I would normally Add Reference and select the missing reference. But `System.Web.Http.Description` is missing from the list. I have sorted the list by name to make sure that I should be able to see it. I can see `System.Web.Http.Data` and .Common etc. but not the .Description one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: System.Web.Http.Description is a namespace inside of System.Web.Http.dll

Comment: I have a reference to System.Web.Http and a using System.Web.Http.Description. I then get the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I un-installed MVC4 and reinstalled from a fresh download. I had to create a NEW project again and the Description namespace appeared.

The strange thing is if I open the old project the Description namespace is still missing when I try to add a using...

Comment: Uninstalling WebApi Nuget Package and re-installing also helps, and is much faster to try than unistalling/reinstalling the full MVC4 stack.

Answer (score 59):

Visual Studio 2012 SPA Template /Help/index.cshtml file was throwing your error.

```
@using System.Web.Http
@using System.Web.Http.Description  <=== CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

**Solution:** Set "Copy Local : True" in properties for References\System.Web.Http

Comment: This worked for me when pulling down a fresh copy of the project from source control and restoring all nuget packages left me with this error.

Comment: +1 - I wasted the better part of the day by trying everything from reinstalling MVC 4 to reinstalling nugget packages. Finally this is the solution that worked.

Comment: Fantastic, succinct answer.  Terrible that the webapi template is broken like this.  Create webapi project, built, ran, broken.  :( Thanks for the fix.

Comment: this worked for me today but curious why it does.  thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**You aren't doing anything wrong**. There is just some configuration problem that prevents Visual Studio from adding the reference to the list of assemblies for the compiler to check.

Types in the `System.Web.Http.Description` are found in the **System.Web.Http.dll** assembly, which is found in a *Nuget* package folder.

You can type `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` in the [NuGet Package Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) and then type `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` to re-install it at which point, the reference will be fixed.

Comment: This was the solution for me, however issuing the following command was simpler `update-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue when while creating  a SPA solution by using MVC-4 framework.
I resolved this by setting the `Copy Local : True` in properties for the reference `System.Web.Http`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was opening the project as a website instead of project/solution. So, after opening the solution it solved my problem.